# How to add characters before and after the text inside a button using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a character before and after the text inside a button using CSS. Not after the button, but inside the text. For eg:- If we have a button with the text "Help me", I want that button to be "[Help me]" using CSS! Like I want Brackets at both ends but not outside the button.

I tried before and after using the button class, and that made me put brackets on the button itself and I want the brackets inside the button before and after the text!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.className::before {
  content: "[ ";
}

.className::after {
  content: " ]";
}
```

```html
<button class="className">Test</button>
```

You can use like this.